# Stereoselectivity in catalytic hydrogenation

Tags: organic-chemistry

Why is *cis* stereo selectivity is observed in this case? See image below.

[image]

I can't think of any reason why *cis* addition is major.

In my opinion, the ratios should be opposite because of easier adsorption of alkene on metal from the front side. So $\ce{H2}$ should be added trans to the methyl group.